# RSpec - programatically determing type of spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was wondering whether it is possible to find out at runtime (i.e. in spec_helper.rb) what kind of spec is being executed (i.e. request, functional etc)?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to add something like a before filter for only a certain type of spec, consider writing:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    # request-spec only before hook
  end
end
```

If you're trying to do something more complicated, you can access the current example's type via `example.metadata[:type]`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after!  For some reason I haven't looked into metadata hash when debugging the example object.

Answer (score 0):

The way the `rspec/rails` project makes this distinction is by checking the file path.

For instance, a request spec will have a file path that matches `/spec\/request/`.

Comment: Is it possible to make the description is the spec_helper?  Calling `File.path(__FILE__)` would return the path to spec_helper.rb itself...